# How do I retrieve the last 10 records from mysql database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird problem. When I run this script I get 10 records from the database but they are all exactly the same. I have no idea what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. Please help me.

I have tables AMCMS_highscores , AMCMS_users , AMCMS_games I want to look inside the AMCMS_highscores table, get the last 10 records but only where the field gameid is 1997 for example. Any help is appreciated.

```
$data = query("SELECT `AMCMS_highscores`.`primkey` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`score` , `AMCMS_users`.`username` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`status` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`userkey` , `AMCMS_games`.`primkey` , `AMCMS_games`.`gamename` FROM `AMCMS_highscores` , `AMCMS_games` , `AMCMS_users` WHERE `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` = '$gameid' AND `AMCMS_highscores`.`userkey` != `AMCMS_users`.`userkey` AND `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` = `AMCMS_games`.`primkey` AND `AMCMS_highscores`.`status`= 'approved' ORDER by `AMCMS_highscores`.`primkey` DESC LIMIT 0, 10");

Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<th>Score:</th> <td>".$info['score'] . "</td> ";
    Print "<th>ID:</th> <td>".$info['userkey'] . " </td></tr>"; }
Print "</table>";
```

Here's a formatted version of the query:

```
SELECT
    `AMCMS_highscores`.`primkey` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` ,
    `AMCMS_highscores`.`score` , `AMCMS_users`.`username` ,
    `AMCMS_highscores`.`status` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`userkey` ,
    `AMCMS_games`.`primkey` , `AMCMS_games`.`gamename`
FROM `AMCMS_highscores` , `AMCMS_games` , `AMCMS_users`
WHERE `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` = '$gameid'
AND `AMCMS_highscores`.`userkey` != `AMCMS_users`.`userkey`
AND `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` = `AMCMS_games`.`primkey`
AND `AMCMS_highscores`.`status`= 'approved'
ORDER by `AMCMS_highscores`.`primkey` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

---

OOPS, i didnt mean to copy that but i did by accident.
When its with "=" sign (highscores.userkey = users.userkey) i get empty query so that didnt fix it :(

I hope this query would be easier to understand :)

```
SELECT highscores.primkey, highscores.gameid, highscores.score, users.username,
highscores.status, highscores.userkey, games.primkey, games.gamename 

FROM AMCMS_highscores AS highscores, AMCMS_games as games, AMCMS_users as users

WHERE highscores.gameid = '$gameid' AND
      highscores.status = 'approved'

ORDER by highscores.primkey DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Here is the result:

http://www.gamesorbiter.com/FB_app/play.php?gameid=1997
(under the game)

Btw, how do you code your query when you post it ? I clicked the code button and only the first line of the code got coded.

Comment: Please format your query to make it readable so that we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to select records from `AMCMS_users` for which there are no matching row in `AMCMS_highscores`, then you need to do a `LEFT JOIN`, and test for NULL values in the joined table.  Here's an extract from [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html):

> If there is no matching row for the
>   right table in the `ON` or `USING`
>   part in a `LEFT JOIN`, a row with all
>   columns set to NULL is used for the
>   right table. You can use this fact to
>   find rows in a table that have no
>   counterpart in another table:

Your query would therefore look more like this:

```
SELECT
    `AMCMS_highscores`.`primkey` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` ,
    `AMCMS_highscores`.`score` , `AMCMS_users`.`username` ,
    `AMCMS_highscores`.`status` , `AMCMS_highscores`.`userkey` ,
    `AMCMS_games`.`primkey` , `AMCMS_games`.`gamename`
FROM `AMCMS_highscores`
LEFT JOIN `AMCMS_users`
    ON `AMCMS_highscores`.`userkey` = `AMCMS_users`.`userkey`
JOIN `AMCMS_games`
    ON `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` = `AMCMS_games`.`primkey`
WHERE `AMCMS_highscores`.`gameid` = '$gameid'
AND `AMCMS_highscores`.`status`= 'approved'
AND `AMCMS_users`.`userkey` = NULL
ORDER by `AMCMS_highscores`.`primkey` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Ignoring the other conditions for a moment, your query is looking at every row in `AMCMS_highscores`, and joining it to every row in `AMCMS_highscores` where `AMCMS_highscores`.`userkey` is not equal to `AMCMS_users`.`userkey`. This will produce a lot of matching rows.  To see what is happening, remove the `LIMIT` clause from your query.

Comment: I wasnt looking for no matching row but the join table fixed everything :) Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing with aliases and a better format:

```
SELECT highscores.primkey, highscores.gameid, highscores.score, users.username,
highscores.status, highscores.userkey, games.primkey, games.gamename 

FROM AMCMS_highscores AS highscores, AMCMS_games as games, AMCMS_users as users

WHERE highscores.gameid = '$gameid' AND
      highscores.userkey != users.userkey AND
      highscores.gameid = games.primkey AND
      highscores.status = 'approved'

ORDER by highscores.primkey DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

You didn't say what the table scheme was, but my guess is that the problem is in the WHERE-part, more specifically `highscores.userkey != users.userkey`. It accepts only users who **don't** have same userkey as in the highscores table. Try changing the `!=` to `=`.